# How to add CircularProgressIndicator to Firebase login?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a login page that is connected to Firebase. When I am logging in, I want to display a CircularProgressIndicator until login is a success. How do I add that?

Login function:

```
  void signIn(String email, String password) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      await _auth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
          .then((_userDoc) => {
                checkUserType(_userDoc.user!.uid),
              })
          .catchError((e) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          msg: "The email or password is invalid. Please check and try again.",
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

Login button:

```
    final loginButton = Material(
      elevation: 5,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      color: Color(0xFF003893),
      child: MaterialButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
          minWidth: 300,
          onPressed: () {
            signIn(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
          },
          child: Text(
            "Login",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          )),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `SmartDialog.showLoading()` from the [flutter_smart_dialog](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_smart_dialog) package at the beggining of your `signIn` method and `SmartDialog.dismiss()` after signIn is done should do it. Plus, you can also use the optional parameters to customize the dialog look and message it shows.

Answer (score 1):

First of all install the package by **flutter pub add flutter_smart_dialog** then, add these two lines in **MaterialApp** as parameters.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorObservers: [FlutterSmartDialog.observer],
      builder: FlutterSmartDialog.init(),
```

finally add **SmartDialog.showLoading()** before await and **SmartDialog.dismiss()**
after await

```
onPressed: () async {
            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                SmartDialog.showLoading(
                    msg: "loading",
                    background: Colors.black54,
                );
            await _authService
            .loginWithEmailAndPassword(
                _email.value.text,
                _password.value.text,
            )
           .then((user) {
               if (user != null) {
                   SmartDialog.dismiss();
                   Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                   context, '/home');
        }
```